# Octave using gnuplot: Diagonals in barplot

Tags: eps, gnuplot, octave

i started using octave figures for my LaTeX-document and i am not quiet satisfied about a small detail about the output pdf:

I am using the bar-option for plotting and in the pdf the diagonals of the bars are drawn, as shown in the attached screenshot. Can someone give me a hint, if (1) this is the usual behavior (using a linux machine) or (2) how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Octave script:

```
x = [1:4];
y = x;
bar(x,y);
grid;
title('testing the font');
print -depslatex  "-SX,Y" "out.tex"
```

Latex Document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{\input{out.tex}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Out.tex generated from octave:

```
% Title: gl2ps_renderer figure
% Creator: GL2PS 1.3.9, (C) 1999-2015 C. Geuzaine
% For: Octave
% CreationDate: Thu Oct 12 13:37:40 2017
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\includegraphics{out-inc}
\end{picture}%
\begin{picture}(576,432)(0,0)
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(164.16,42.5189){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(253.44,42.5189){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{2}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(342.72,42.5189){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{3}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(432,42.5189){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{4}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(69.8755,47.52){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{0}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(69.8755,135.54){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(69.8755,223.56){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{2}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(69.8755,311.58){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{3}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(69.8755,399.6){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{4}}}}
\fontsize{11}{0}
\selectfont\put(298.08,409.6){\makebox(0,0)[b]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{testing the font}}}}
\end{picture}
```

output:
[image: diagonals]

Comment: can you include the tex file? You shouldn't need resize box if it is generated by TeX.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you for your help: if i don't use the resize box i get: "Overfull \hbox (231.0pt too wide) in paragraph" Also it seems to work only with PdfLaTeX as compiler, not with the default LaTeX.

Comment: That's a warning not an error. And we can't help without seeing the contents of the `out.tex` file.

Comment: ah, i thought you meant include instead of input, sorry for the misunderstanding- i now edited question. Do you need the original .eps file as well? I think i can't upload it here.

Comment: I get the same output at least (Kubuntu, Octave 4.0.0), the lines are visible when viewing the EPS in Okular, but not in Evince. Try `-dpdflatex` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same output, but when using the `-dpdflatex` driver instead of `-depslatex` for the `print` in Octave, the result looks good. Perhaps there is a difference in how the bars are rendered between the two.

Result with `print -dpdflatex "-SX,Y" "out.tex"`:

[image: dpdflatex bars]

You can find more infos at: [Manual for Plotting and Saving Plots](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html)